# Using HTMLAgillity Pack to output formatted lists

Tags: c#, html, string, list, html-agility-pack

Hi I have the following HTML list:

```
<ol><li>klndzldgnldzl</li>
    <li>zdkgnlkzdngzlkdgn</li>
    <li>dzlknglkdznglkzdn</li></ol>
```

Currently I am using HTMLAgillityPack to format the list to the following format:

```
  * klndzldgnldzl
  * zdkgnlkzdngzlkdgn
  * dzlknglkdznglkzdn
```

Here are the methods that I am using to format the list:

```
public static string ConvertToPlainText(string html)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, sw);
            sw.Flush();
            return sw.ToString();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Count the words.
        /// The content has to be converted to plain text before (using ConvertToPlainText).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">The plain text.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int CountWords(string plainText)
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText) ? plainText.Split(' ', '\n').Length : 0;
        }


        public static string Cut(string text, int length)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Length > length)
            {
                text = text.Substring(0, length - 4) + " ...";
            }
            return text;
        }


        private static void ConvertContentTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode subnode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                ConvertTo(subnode, outText);
            }
        }


        private static void ConvertTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
        {
            string html;
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case HtmlNodeType.Comment:
                    // don't output comments
                    break;

                case HtmlNodeType.Document:
                    ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
                    break;

                case HtmlNodeType.Text:
                    // script and style must not be output
                    string parentName = node.ParentNode.Name;
                    if ((parentName == "script") || (parentName == "style"))
                        break;

                    // get text
                    html = ((HtmlTextNode)node).Text;

                    // is it in fact a special closing node output as text?
                    if (HtmlNode.IsOverlappedClosingElement(html))
                        break;

                    // check the text is meaningful and not a bunch of whitespaces
                    if (html.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        outText.Write(HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(html));
                    }
                    break;

                case HtmlNodeType.Element:
                    switch (node.Name)
                    {

                        case "li":
                              outText.Write("\r\n* "); // FORMATS THE LIST
                          //  outText.Write("\r\n");
                            break;
                        case "p":
                            // treat paragraphs as crlf
                            outText.Write("\r\n");
                            break;
                        case "br":
                            outText.Write("\r\n");
                            break;
                    }

                    if (node.HasChildNodes)
                    {
                        ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

---

```
string s = "<ol><li>klndzldgnldzl</li><li>zdkgnlkzdngzlkdgn</li <li>dzlknglkdznglkzdn</li></ol>"
var lala  = ConvertToPlainText(s); // Formated Text
```

My question would be is there a way to output the list in the following format:

1. klndzldgnldzl
2. zdkgnlkzdngzlkdgn
3. dzlknglkdznglkzdn

I would imagine running a for loop trough the nodes would be required somewhere but i have not enough in depth knowledge in HTMLAgillity pack to achieve this.

Comment: Would you care to explain us why?

Comment: download a PDF, Excel anything that would not interpret HTML elements.

Comment: For your own sanity, rather use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp).

Comment: @IanKemp any examples anywhere? The documentation is quite poor...